# Define zoom area with anything zoomer

Tags: jquery, zooming

I want to use a png (an image of a magnifying glass) but I only want to have the zoom area where the lens of the magnifying glas, i.e. I want to be able define the area. Is this possible with anythingzoom if not is there any other plugin out there? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

zoomable elements  will have a common class and based on that , on hover zoom it

like this

http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples

http://technicolorenvy.github.io/jquery-zoombox/